# Why is my function returning a sparse array (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend

I'm learning Javascript. This is a problem I'm stuck on:

"Using a for loop, calculate the percentage of students' test scores stored in the *testScore* array. The test has a total of 100. Store the percentages in another array and display it to the console."

This was my solution (I know there's "better" alternative methods of solving this, but since I'm just learning, I'd rather understand first what I'm doing wrong here.):

```
const testScore = [10, 40, 30, 25];
const percentages = [];

const gradePercentage = (scores) => {
  percentages[scores] = (scores / 100) * 100;
  return percentages;
};

for (let i = 0; i < testScore.length; i++) {
  gradePercentage(testScore[i]);
}

console.log(percentages);
```

I got the calculations right, but when trying to store it in another array, I get "empty" slots. Why?

This is what the console displayed:

[image: console]

Comment: What result do you actually expect? Provide the **exact** output you wanted.

Comment: I was expecting (4) [10, 25, 30, 40]. Basically, only the 4 values in the "percentages" array, not empty x n.

Comment: Right, so you see you want the value `10` to be put at the beginning of the array. What you're doing instead: `percentages[scores] = ...` <- you're putting a value to the `scores` index. You probably need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: You also don't "calculate the percentage of students' test scores stored in the testScore array" --- `(scores / 100) * 100` <- your evaluation is wrong, if you divide something by 100, then multiply by 100 you get the same original value*.

Comment: Ohh I see -- thanks! Yes, I figured multiplying and dividing by 100 would get me the original value. I changed the values from the original problem temporarily so that I didn't have to grab a calculator every time I needed to check if my calculations were right. :p